# Big-O of a function taking on a negative value?

Tags: math, big-o

Hello I was wondering what would be my Big-Oh for this function: f(n) = 7n – 3nlogn+100000. I checked other similar questions. Some say that since nlogn is -3 we can ignore it and as such the result is O(n). I check with my professor and he said no we don't ignore the negative and still choose the largest of them all and as such the Big-Oh would be O(nlogn). Not ignoring the negative I end up with this. Am I right??

```
7n – 3nlogn+100000 ≤ (7+3+10000) nlogn      where c= 100010 & n≥n0 
7n – 3nlogn+100000 ≤ 100010 nlogn       n0= 2

O(nlogn) – Linear logarithmic or linearithmic
```

or is it more like

```
7n - 3nlogn + 100000 ≤ 100010 n          where c= 100010 & n≥n0  & n0 = 1
```

Thanks alot

Comment: Sounds like homework to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the formal definition of big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), you'll notice that f(x) = O(g(x)) iff there are constants c and x<sub>0</sub> such that

> ∀x > x<sub>0</sub>. |f(x)| ≤ c|g(x)|

Notice that there are absolute value bars here.  Consequently, while it's true that

> 7n - 3nlogn + 100000 ≤ 100010 n

under the circumstances you mentioned, you would really need to show that

> |7n - 3nlogn + 100000| ≤ 100010 |n|

which is not in general true.  Using the fact that you need to have absolute value bars, you can prove that this function is Θ(n log n) by repeating your analysis, but taking care to watch for the sign flip.  One way to do this is to use the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality):

> |7n - 3n log n + 100000|
>
> ≤ |7n| + |-3n log n| + |100000|
>
> = 7|n| + 3|n log n| + |100000|
>
> ≤ 7n + 3n log n + 100000
>
> < 7n log n + 3n log n + 100000 n log n (when n > 10, say)
>
> = 100010 n log n

So the function is O(n log n).  You can repeat this analysis to get a matching lower bound as well.

Hope this helps!